# Multiline button breaks width calculation of Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-linearlayout

I have an ugly error in my app and I have no idea how to fix it. See at first this two screenshots:

[image]

As you might can see there is one button with a too big text so it wraps (that the text is cut does not matter here). I guess that this text causes a calculations bug in the LinearLayout: I in one of the measure steps are all width cumulated, the width will be bigger then the aviable space, so it will just take the hole width instead of using the aviable width and split it over all elements.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dialog_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dialog_horizontal_margin"/>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/SlideButtonContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="yes"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="no"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="maybe"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dialog_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dialog_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Test 2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/SlideButtonContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="one"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="more then one million"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="infinity"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally here is the missing style:

```
<style name="SlideButtonContainer">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/dialog_horizontal_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/dialog_horizontal_margin</item>
    <item name="android:background">#44000000</item>
    <item name="android:baselineAligned">false</item>
</style>
```

Do you guys have an idea how to fix this layout issue?

Comment: Setting a layout_weight to the same value on each button will always make them the same width, regardless of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quiet simple solution. Since I know where the text will been wraped I just added a `\n` in the String so the calculation of the width was fixed. Not a solution at all, but a nice workaround without hacks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my project. My solution was to add a wrapper linear layout and assign weight to it. On the inner button I just set the width and height to match_parent. I have the root layout width to be wrap content so the button with big text takes the biggest space and that space would be the height of the parent. Other smaller buttons would just extend to the available height. Code should explain it more clearly:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"       
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"       
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        android:layout_weight="1"
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"          
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"      
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"            
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In my original code that linearlayout is already in a vertical linearlayout, or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @rekire you didnot misunderstand. I solved this problem using this code. I am placing linearlayout inside linearlayout knowingly to solve the problem you are facing. If this code doesnot work or you need more explanation please ask after trying.

Comment: @rekire my code is only for the problem part <LinearLayout
        style="@style/SlideButtonContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

Comment: I tried it and it does not work, by the way I needed to add a `android:layout_weight="1"` to the inner `LinearLayout` else the width was zero ;) (Or was that your intent? This would fix it too Haha :-D)

Comment: @rekire yes it is needed to add the weight. It was added yesterday but during editing I accidently removed it.